# Helm chart for installing PyPi?

Tags: python, kubernetes, pypi, kubernetes-helm

Been searching for days for a Helm chart to install a PyPi server (version irrelavant at this point) to a Kubernetes cluster.  Finding practically nothing.

Any and all help would be appreciated.  How does one use a helm chart to install a PyPi server to a Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't succeed in finding a Helm chart for Pypi either, but would it be an option to create a simple K8s deployment on your own using an existing docker image?
You could have a look at [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/pypiserver/pypiserver) and try to deploy it similar to [this example](https://codeburst.io/getting-started-with-kubernetes-deploy-a-docker-container-with-kubernetes-in-5-minutes-eb4be0e96370)

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to find a ready-made and test Helm chart for `pypiserver`.

Alas, couldn't find and so created it myself:
https://gitlab.com/softmill/package-management/pypiserver

It's really minimal at this stage, but it does the job.
Your mileage may vary.
May contain nuts.
PRs are welcome.